# Anonymous Variables read only case

Tags: c#-4.0

An annonymous type can consume memory in two ways.

**First Way**

```
public MyAdd MyFunc()
        {
            return new MyAdd
            {
                name = "Mike",
                Address = "MyTown"
            };
        }


var x = MyFunc();
```

**Second Way**

```
x = new { name = "Mike", Address = "MyTown" };
```

The difference in these two statement is that the c.name is readonly in case of former and 
is modifyable in later case.

My question is, in both cases finally an annonymous type is consuming some value so why in 
case of structure it is not read only. Is there any internal mechanism for this?

Comment: I seen in first way it's not an anonymous type...it's MyAdd type. Because of it's not anonymous type, you can set values and properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in your first case you're *not* using an anonymous type. The first code is equivalent to:

```
var tmp = new MyAdd();
tmp.name = "Mike";
tmp.Address = "MyTown";
return tmp;
```

No extra type is introduced. I know it *looks* like the syntax for an *anonymous-object-creation-expression* or *anonymous object initializer* (those are the terms the spec uses) but  it's really just using the existing type. This is just an object creation expression using an object initializer - there's nothing anonymous here.

See sections 7.6.10.1 and 7.6.10.2 of the C# 4 spec for more information.

Comment: please share the link for the above mentioned sections

Comment: @StackOverflowUser: The spec isn't online in a particularly useful form which can be linked to easily, but you can download it: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc (I keep a list of specs with links at http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Specifications.aspx)

Comment: @PankajGarg: Any reason for unaccepting this? Is there more information I can help you with?